# QMAKE make install - how to disable 'all' target dependency?

Tags: qt, makefile, build-process, qmake

for some reasons, we're using QMAKE for managing our C++ dev projects.

Ok, not really my favourite cross-build system, but I've to live with it...ahh, my question.

When you create QMAKE projects with INSTALL target where you, the resulting Makefile does always contain a `make install`install target which looks alike:

```
install: install_target  FORCE
...
install_target: all FORCE
...
```

where the `all` target is basically the build all target...

So, as I see it. Qmake does always recheck the targets whether there are changes and rebuilt the respective targets if there are any. In some of our projects with heavy linking, this costs a lot of time.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I've just no idea :/

Thanks!

Comment: What costs a lot of time? The checking or the rebuilding? If the rebuilding is taking time is the issue that you don't want it to rebuild even if it has to? Or is the issue that it rebuilds even when you think it *shouldn't* have to? If the checking is taking a long time how large is the project?

Comment: Mostly the rebuilding...the checking takes some time too, but thats negligible in comparison to the rebuilding. 

I think we have the "don't want it to rebuild even if it has to" case :)  any idea?

Comment: Not rebuilding even if it has to is a bad idea and against the very concept of `make` and other build tools. They are designed to do **exactly** that. Rebuild your project when/if things change so that you don't need to *remember* to manually clean and rebuild or force a full rebuild to be sure you have a clean up-to-date build. Why are you needing to rebuild often enough for this to be a problem? Are things changing? If not then why is it rebuilding at all?

Comment: Yeah, right. Problem here is our system architecture. We are using a centralized repo (really silly - we have hg here but use a single clone on our NFS for the whole system :/). Building our core system took around 15 minutes on a distcc-cluster with 40 i7-machines. Thanks to our single-clone-architecture here, there are ongoing changes whenever we're building the system and thus `make install` will always rebuild...

Please, do not get me wrong. I know your right and if I could, I would change things here, but I can't.

Comment: The problem is as *soon* as you do that you start running the risk of not being sure that your builds are sane. You can't know which parts didn't get rebuilt and which are out of date. When your builds stop being sane all sorts of pain and horrors ensue. 15 minutes to build just changed pieces or 15 minutes to build the whole thing clean? Especially with distcc in the mix you should really not be rebuilding much when little (or nothing) changes. I'd try to make sure that the builds are actually only building what needs to be rebuilt and not rebuilding everything (or cleaning everything).

Comment: Sadly, that's not under my control. Most of the times, my colleagues are rebuilding everything.
But thanks for your advice and recommendations. Maybe I can change the workflow of the guys here...but I've not much hope. 
So, back to my original question. Do you have any idea how I can disable the `all`-target dependency for the `install` target?

Comment: No idea. You could do it by manually editing the Makefile possibly but like I said this is a *spectacularly* bad idea.

Comment: Ah, no. That's really a bad idea :) Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Makefile` has a list of dependencies for each object (`*.obj` file), like related C or C++ file, and even all included headers.

Hence my make executable only rebuilds an object **if** any dependency's modify-date is newer than that of the related object itself.

You could create a VSCode [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796193/8740349),
that adds "`Save as Old`" feature/option to `File` menu (`Ctrl+Alt+S`), which sets file's modify-date to 2000-1-1 (without showing the Save-as dialog), finally, use that feature whenever you decide that the change should not need a rebuild.

**WARNING:** I previously did something similar, for headers only, and even then often my decesion to skip the **partial one hour build** was wrong, causing me to wonder "what's wrong?", and would end up doing a **complete 5 hour** rebuild  ;-)

**Note** that my project has/had around 3 GB source-code, and on a Core i5 CPU would take 5 hours to build, however, even then I decided to never use "Save as Old" unless I only change doc-comments, I mean, if you have less source-code don't bother creating/using such extension.